# Error al generar posicion 0 con valores de un Array - Angular 10

Tags: angular

Tengo una instancia como array y la relleno con un constructor pero me lanza el siguiente error.
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Estoy mapeando un json y cuando en el json viene un array de plow funciona super bien pero no siempre va llegar un array plow y hay es cuando me lanza la excepcion y estoy tratando de rellenar esa posicion 0 con el objeto del constructor pero no me fuciona para que asi no me lence error en el html de que un valor indefinido

Clase de Plow

```
constructor(kilo, nano, aceit, ree, conn) {
        this.kil = kilo;
        this.nan = nano;
        this.aceite = aceit;
        this.rree = ree;
        this.connec = conexion;
    }

 kil:String;
 nan:String;
 aceite:String;
 rree:String;
 connec:String;
```

```
plow: ParameterLow[] = [];
this.plow[0] = new ParameterLow('kkkk','nnnn',true,true,false); --> El error lo da aca pero nose por que
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puedas comprender mejor.

```
/**
 * En esta línea creamos nuestra variable plow,
 * definimos que sea de tipo Array del objeto ParameterLow
 * Así mismo la inicializamos como un arreglo vacío
 **/
const plow: ParameterLow[] = [];
```

**¿Como podemos anexarle información si el arreglo no tiene información?** *lo podemos hacer de la siguiente forma*:

```
plow.push(new ParameterLow('kkkk','nnnn',true,true,false));
```

Otra forma es crear el arreglo e inicializarlo con información, como se ve a continuación:

```
const plow: ParameterLow[] = [new ParameterLow('kkkk','nnnn',true,true,false)];
```

Como ya sabemos que el arreglo que hemos creado cuenta con información, podemos explicar, que de la forma que planteas, sirve para acceder a una posición existente en nuestro arreglo y asignarle un nuevo valor a almacenar, pambien podemos manipular la información que tengamos en dicha posición

```
/**
 * De esta forma le asignamos un nuevo objeto en la pocision 0
 **/
plow[0] = new ParameterLow('lllll','mmmm',false,false,true);
```

Dejo un enlace en el cual puedas conocer un poco mas a fondo el tema de los Array: [Array Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Las otras formas ya las habia echo pero la que me sirvio que no conocia fue esta:

`const plow: ParameterLow[] = [new ParameterLow('kkkk','nnnn',true,true,false)];`

Answer (score 0):

Es porque el arreglo está vacío y no hay nada en la posición 0.

Usa el método push en el constructor:

```
constructor(){
   this.plow.push(new ParameterLow('kkkk','nnnn',true,true,false))
}
```

Comment: y eso deberia ir en el constructor del componente donde hago la instanacia o en el constructor de la clase Plow ?

Comment: como dices me da el siguiente error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined